# TAdvToolBarSeparatorというコンポーネント

Tags: c++

現在、Borland C++ Builder6で作成されたプロジェクトをembarcadero c++ builder10.3 communityでビルドができないかを探っています。

Main.cppというファイルがあるのですが、まずこのcppファイル内で使用されているC++ Builderのコンポーネントファイルを知りたくMain.hファイルというのを見ていくと、その一覧のようなところを見つけました。

```
------（中略）------------------------------------------------------
class TfrmMain : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TAdvDockPanel *AdvDockPanel1;
    TAdvToolBar *AdvToolBar1;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnServerStart;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnServerStop;
    TPopupMenu *TryMenu;
    TMenuItem *Close1;
    TMenuItem *Show1;
    TPopupMenu *ListItemMenu;
    TMenuItem *MenuItem1;
    TMenuItem *DeleteList;
    TIdTCPServer *Server;
    TIdThreadMgrDefault *IdThreadMgrDefault1;
    TAdvToolBarSeparator *AdvToolBarSeparator1;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnSetup;
    TImageList *ImageList1;
    TComPort *Serial;
    TTimer *AliveTimer;
    TMediaPlayer *MPlay;
    TSaveDialog *SaveDialog;
    TAdvListView *DevListView;
    TAdvToolBarSeparator *AdvToolBarSeparator2;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnMute;
    TTimer *AudioTimer;
    TIdMessage *IdMsg;
    TIdSMTP *IdSMTP1;
    TAdvMemo *memMsg;
    TStatusBar *StatusBar1;
    TMenuItem *StopAction;
    TMenuItem *StartAction;
    TMenuItem *AudioStop;
    TMenuItem *N1;
    TMenuItem *N2;
    TIdTCPServer *M06Config;
    TIdThreadMgrDefault *IdThreadMgrDefault2;
    TAdvToolBarSeparator *AdvToolBarSeparator3;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnOpen;
    TAdvToolBarButton *tbtnSave;
    TOpenDialog *OpenDialog;
------（中略）------------------------------------------------------
```

c++ builder10.3 communityのIDEで

TPopupMenuやTIdTCPServerなどは、パレットの検索ボックスで検索ができるのですが、いくつかのコンポーネントは検索できませんでした。

例えば、”TAdvToolBarSeparator”というものなどが検索できなかったのですが、
この検索できないコンポーネントというのは、どこかのサードパーティーから購入したコンポーネントということでしょうか？
また、TAdvToolBarSeparatorというコンポーネントはどのようなコンポーネントなのでしょうか？
また、購入方法などをご教示よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: これあたりでは？ [TMS Advanced Toolbars & Menus](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev.asp)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。[TMS](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev.asp)のサイトに行ってみるとトライアル版がダウンロードできるようになっていて、インストールしてみたところ”TAdvTool*”と頭に付くコンポーネントを呼び出せるようになりました。